# Is it ok to make repeated SMB socket connections

Tags: python, sockets, smb

I want to monitor an SMB connection, I've cooked up the code below but I'm worried I may be tying up the network.

Is it OK to repeatedly open and close a connection in this manner?

```
import socket
import time
import threading

class SMBConnectionMonitor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, poll_period=60, timeout=5):
        super(SMBConnectionMonitor, self).__init__()

        self.host = host
        self.poll_period = poll_period
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.connected = False
        self.stop_requested = False

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_requested = True

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_requested:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
            try:
                sock.connect((self.host, 445))
                # successful, if this is the first time update the status
                if not self.connected:
                    self.connected = True
            except socket.error as e:
                # can't connect, if this is first time update the status
                if self.connected:
                    self.connected = False
            sock.close()

            # wait for the poll period before trying another connection
            for i in range(self.poll_period):
                if self.stop_requested: return
                time.sleep(1)

monitor = SMBConnectionMonitor("remote-computer", poll_period=10)
monitor.start()
monitor.join(timeout=30)
monitor.stop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening and closing a connection like this once a second would generate negligible traffic even over dial-up. Even if you removed the delay from the loop completely, it would have a very small, probably not even noticeable, impact on a modern network. The relatively slow speed of Python combined with the delays inherent with starting a TCP connection means that even if you tried you can't come anywhere close to tying up the the network by repeatedly opening and closing one connection.